# Creating MongoDB Start-up script

Tags: linux, mongodb, startup

I have been struggling on creating mongodb start-up script.

I have this file here "script.js" that contain my scripts that i want to execute every-time the server boot.

My script file is under "/opt/temp/script.js"

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
  print(collection);
});
```

Which command should I write to execute this file every time after the sever restarted ?
Where to put that command ? 
Please help me

Thanks you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I managed to get it working I created `Script.js`file with my mongoDb commands and place it at /op/myscripts. Then on the `mongodb-conf`I included the command to execute my script once mongodb is started command `mongo /opt/myscripts/script.js`.

Comment: How exactly did you configure mongodb-conf to run a script? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What version of Linux are you using, what version of MongoDB have you installed, and how did you install it?

If, for example, you installed Mongodb on Ubuntu as per [the MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) you should have a start up script in **/etc/init.d/mongod** which will auto-start MongoD on boot.

If you have installed, say, a release candidate in a non standard location, I found [these scripts](https://github.com/syokenz/mongodb-init-script) to be fairly good and very alterable.

Using this script will NOT guarantee `mongod` starting on boot. You'll need to use [sysv-rc-conf](http://nickgeoghegan.net/linux/handy-package-sysv-rc-conf) to set the run-levels correctly, like the apache2 line in the image linked.

Comment: Hi Nick Thanks for response I'm  using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11, I think my question was not clear enough I have mongodb running on Start-up fine what i want to is I want to be able to run some mongo commands saved in the "script.js" file I mentioned above on the start-up ? 
I hope this is clear enough